# Rsync through posix_spawn

Tags: c++, c, posix, rsync

I have an rsync daemon running and I can execute the following command successfully:

rsync --port=1873 -avWh 127.0.0.1::jackfruit_peers/data.0a6 /home/v/data

but from the code:

local_dir = /home/v/data

remote_dir = 127.0.0.1::jackfruit_peers/data.0a6

```
    pid_t child_pid;
    char cmd[] = "rsync -avWh --port=1873";
    char *argv[] = {cmd, remote_dir, local_dir,
                    (char*) 0}; 
    if (0 != posix_spawn(&child_pid, "/usr/bin/rsync", NULL, NULL, argv, environ)) {
        logger::error("posix spawn");
        return ERR_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
```

I get the error:

> rsync: failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
>   (111) rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128)
>   [Receiver=3.1.0] 2015-01-16 15:27:08.421.732 28623 0x7fbc01914010 INFO
>   Waking up parent whose child pid=30060. errno=0

Any idea why?

EDIT: the rsync handle is defined as:

```
 [jackfruit_peers]
    comment = for data transfer
    path = /home/jackfruit/
    read only = yes
    timeout  =  60
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed to this ugly format and it works:

```
   pid_t child_pid;
    char a1[] = "rsync";
    char a2[] = "-avWh";
    char a3[] = "--port=1873";
    char *argv[] = {a1, a2, a3, remote_dir, local_dir,
                   (char*)0};

    if (0 != posix_spawn(&child_pid, "/usr/bin/rsync", NULL, NULL, argv, environ)) {
        logger::error("posix spawn");
        return ERR_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
```

I was getting deprecated string conversions from const char* to char* when I was using actual string constants in place of a1, a2, a3 and hence I had foolishly clubbed everything into:

```
char cmd[] = "rsync -avWh --port=1873";
```